# Spring Boot Jpa filter children

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Boot JPA specification for filtering records according to the filter criteria. I have a Parent and 2 child tables. These two child tables has another common parent2. I need to retrieve Parent record along with child records that matches the common parent2 id.

```
select * from parent 
join child1 on ...
join child2 on ...
where child1.another_parent_id = ... or
child2.another_parent_id = ...
```

Problem here is it retrieves parent record and if I do parent.getChild1 or parent.getChild2 it returns all the records of child1 and child2, not just the matching records of another_parent_id.

Is it possible to achieve this with Spring Boot jpa specification ?

One way that I have is to have separate repository for child1 and child2 and filter the results and combine and get the results. Here I need to hit 2 queries and also if both the results of child1 and child2 returns same parent then, I need to filter the unique records.

Comment: can you provide a small sample project/git repo? it could help to cplarify your need.

Answer (score 1):

Along with the parent record, you can capture the child records as well that is returned by the query. You can map the query results to the DTO.

1. Define a DTO:

   ```
   @Getter
   @Setter
   @NoArgsConstructor
   @AllArgsConstructor
   public class ResultDto implements Serializable {
      private Parent p;
      private Child1 ch1;
      private Child2 ch2;
   }
   ```
2. Query and map the results to dto.

   ```
   @Query("SELECT new com.jpatest.jpaexploration.dto.ResultDto(p, ch1, ch2) FROM parent p join Child1 ch1 on ... join Child2 ch2 on ... where ch1.another_parent_id = ... or ch2.another_parent_id = ...")
   List<ResultDto> getResults();
   ```

This list of dto will contain only children that were returned by the query.